# Joomla ajax call function inside controller

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to call a function inside controller that will return a echo 
but I get error as result show inside my id `#ly-id-result`

```
{"success":false,"message":"View not found [name, type, prefix]: places, raw, hpj_storemanagerView","messages":null,"data":null}
```

My Ajax call in : httpdocs/modules/mod_storemanager_map/tmpl/default.php

```
var ly_inputVal = document.getElementById("ly-val-inp").value;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "index.php?format=raw&option=com_storemanager&task=abc",
    data: {text:ly_inputVal},
    method: "POST", //Use post method
    cache: false, //Specify no cache
    success: function(result){
        //console.log(ly_inputVal);
        jQuery("#ly-id-result").html(result);
    }
});
```

in my controller in : httpdocs/components/com_storemanager/controller.php

```
public function abc() 
{
    // Get Joomla's input object:
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

    // Get the variable
    $value = $input->get('ly_inputVal');

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error; I have to change

`$value = $input->get('ly_inputVal');`

to

`$value = $input->get('text');`

Now it working